# Tensorflow not properly decoding an image

Tags: python, image-processing, matplotlib, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow. I am reading images from files and decoding them with tf.image.decode_jpeg and then I am plotting decoded image with matplotlib. But somehow original and decoded images are different.

[image: This is original Image]

[image: This is decoded image plotted with matplotlib]

```
filenames = ['/Users/darshak/TensorFlow/100.jpg', '/Users/darshak/TensorFlow/10.jpg']
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)

reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
filename, content = reader.read(filename_queue)

image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(content, channels=3)

image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)

resized_image = tf.image.resize_images(image, [256, 256])

image_batch = tf.train.batch([resized_image], batch_size=9)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

plt.imshow(image.eval())
plt.show()
sess.close()
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using to plot the image?

Comment: Without code, my best guess is you are using OpenCV to load the images, which loads them as BGR and matplotlib them, which plots them as RGB, which creates a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem arises because `plt.imshow(image.eval())` interprets the image data different depending on the element type of `image`.

- If `image` is a `tf.uint8` tensor (i.e. as it is produced by `tf.image.decode_jpeg()`) it will contain values from `0` to `255` for the R, G, and B channels, and `plt.imshow()` interprets `(0, 0, 0)` as black and `(255, 255, 255)` as white.
- When you cast `image` to be a `tf.float32` tensor, it will contain values from `0.0` to `255.0` for the R, G, and B channels, and `plt.imshow()` interprets `(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)` as black, but it interprets **`(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)`** as white. All values greater than `1.0` are treated the same as `1.0`, and as a result the image appears discolored.

If you intend to represent the image as a `tf.float32` tensor and visualize it, you should divide the image values by `255.0`:

```
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(content, channels=3)
image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255.0
```

Comment: Which algorithm, i.e. dct method,  is used by `tf.image.decode_jpeg` to produce the image. According to the documentation, dct method `Defaults to "". string specifying a hint about the algorithm used for decompression. Defaults to "" which maps to a system-specific default. Currently valid values are ["INTEGER_FAST", "INTEGER_ACCURATE"]`. How can I find out if my system is using INTEGER_ACCURATE or INTEGER_FAST?